# how remove stored password - Excel connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, connection

I retrieve data *from SQL Server* database *to excel* file.
When I define connection properties, I choose that I want store password.

Meanwhile, I create a new login (and grant only access to read only data from specified database).
Unfortunately I am unable to find any option in Excel to remove this stored password.
In files which defining connections (.odc extension), I found information about login, but nothing about password.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe obvious, but did you try to **unckeck** the `Save password` checkbox in the connection properties window and **reconnect** to the database?

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx